# Rails 3 has_many through scope with joins returns unexpected results

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, scope, has-many-through

I am trying to create scopes to find all Galleries by a specific category type, like "Style".  Eventually, they will be chained to filter by multiple category types, but I can't get the first to work.

Here are the models:

Gallery:

```
has_many :gallery_categories, :class_name => "GalleryCategories", :dependent => :destroy
has_many :categories, :through => gallery_categories
has_many :colors, :through => gallery_categories, :source => :category, :conditions => {:type => "Color"}
has_many :styles, :through => gallery_categories, :source => :category, :conditions => {:type => "Style"}
```

...and many more types of categories...

Category:

```
:has_many :gallery_categories
:has_many :galleries, :through => :gallery_categories
```

GalleryCategories:

```
:belongs_to :gallery
:belongs_to :category
```

I am trying to do something like this in Gallery:

```
:scope :by_style, lambda {|style| joins(:styles).where(:category => {:name => style})}
```

Then, for example, I run 
    Gallery.by_style("Contemporary")

And I am returned 181 Galleries when there are only 40 Galleries, and in this example there should only be one returned with the style "Contemporary".

Here is the resulting SQL:

```
SELECT `galleries`.* FROM `galleries` INNER JOIN `gallery_categories` ON `galleries`.`id` = `gallery_categories`.`gallery_id` INNER JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`type` = 'Style' WHERE `categories`.`name` = 'Contemporary'
```

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.